# Update model after click on img AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i'm new in AngularJS and i'm trying to update my model after that the user click on img, this is my code :

```
<div class="col-xs-4 text-center"><a ng-model="user.plateforme" value="ios"><img src="ios.png" class="img-circle img-responsive"></a></div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="update(user)">Save changes</a>
</div>
      <pre>form = {{user | json}}</pre>
```

and my controller :

```
angular.module('formExample', [])
      .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.master = {};

        $scope.update = function(user) {
          $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
        };

        $scope.reset = function() {
          $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
        };

        $scope.reset();
      }]);
```

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `ng-click`. This will cause your model to automatically digest:

```
<img src="ios.png" class="img-circle img-responsive" ng-click="reset();">
```

Here I assume that you want to call `$scope.reset()`, but you can create whatever method you want there.